# Radio button and popover for a tablet

Tags: radio-button, tooltip, popover

I am trying to use radio buttons for a number of choices on a page that I am working on. When the button is selected I want to show a small popover that indicates what the button means e.g. A = 'do this' or B = 'don't do that'. 
It works fine on a desktop, but on a tablet I have to press the button twice.
Are there any tools that can facilitate this for use on a tablet?

```
 <tr>
       <td class="form-group col-md-6">Is there an indication for the drug?</td>

       <td id="Indication" class="form-group col-md-6">




           <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Indicated"><input type="radio" name="indication" id="a1" value="0" <?php echo $a1; ?> required>A</input></p>
           <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Marginally Indicated"><input type="radio" name="indication" id="a2" value="0" <?php echo $a2; ?> required>B</input></p>
           <p class="radio-inline" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Not Indicated"><input type="radio" name="indication" id="a3" value="3" <?php echo $a3; ?> required>C</input></p>

       </td>
       </tr>
```

Comment: what tablet, and what browser on that tablet?

Comment: I have been testing it on an ipad, safari browswer

Comment: which ipad and version of safari?

Comment: ipad mini 1, latest safari

Comment: are you sure it's needing to click twice, and not just slow? there is a 300ms delay between tapping and the input being checked on mobile browsers

Comment: It definitely requires two clicks, I have tried it numerous times, I have looked at different tooltip options, toogle, focus, hover etc